# How to configure a Power BI Visual to display string values in a matrix?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm new to Power BI Visual development, and struggling to configure my data roles and data view mappings. I want to create a roadmap visual that has columns for each quarter across a time span, rows for each team that is working on the project, and in the cells showing the **name** of the deliverables that are scheduled for the various quarters.
There can be multiple values in the same cell, and the same deliverable might appear with multiple dates to show that incremental deployments are planned.

(Apologies for the table formatting, during the edit it shows up correctly, but once I post it just shows up as text...)

My input data is something like this:
| Team   |  Deliverable  |  Date   | other columns for further formatting... |
| ------ | ------------- | ------- | --------------------------------------- |
| Team 1 | Deliverable 1 | 2024 Q3 | |
| Team 1 | Deliverable 1 | 2025 Q2 | |
| Team 1 | Deliverable 2 | 2024 Q3 | |
| Team 1 | Deliverable 3 | 2024 Q4 | |
| Team 2 | Deliverable 4 | 2024 Q3 | |
| Team 2 | Deliverable 4 | 2024 Q4 | |

What I want to display is something like this:
| Team | 2024 Q3 | 2024 Q4 | 2025 Q1 | 2025 Q2 |
| ---- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| Team 1 | Deliverable 1, Deliverable 2 | Deliverable 3 | | Deliverable 1 |
| Team 2 | Deliverable 4 | Deliverable 4 | | |

In my `capabilities.json` file I tried using categorical, table, and matrix dataViewMappings, but my problem is that Power BI expects a "measure" kind for values, which can only be numerical.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by Power Query

Full Video of the solution in [yourtube](https://youtu.be/H-Q-Om2ESdM)

1. use group by of `Team` and `Date` and `aggregate (sum)` on `Deliverable` column
2. you would get something like this `= Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {" Team ", " Date "}, {{"Deliverable", each List.Sum([#" Deliverable "]), type nullable text}})`
3. you will get a column with error
4. replace `each List.Sum` with `each Text.Combine` this will get you result
5. use the table to create matrix and please new column to the value in matrix and you please around with row and column

Comment: Thank you for this, this is a great solution if there is indeed only a need to display text.
In my case, I'm developing a custom visual because I want to further format each deliverable based on some other column values. E.g. if the delivery is late, its color should be different; or display certain icons next to the deliverable name based on other column values. 
Also, a limitation of the built-in Matrix visual is that for a certain date there are no values, then that column will be missing from the overall visual, like 2025 Q1 in the above example.

Comment: @DanielSH, I Have given solution to what you have asked. Yes, you can do that too, there are multiple tricks. All you have to do is manipulate the data. Data Manipulation is the biggest take in the analysis and reporting. Stack give you an idea when you get stuck at some point in your code, but not the complete project or code.

Comment: @DanielSH you can right to me on techtrickda@gmail.com, I will check on it, please do subscribe